# What is the difference between Session and ViewData in Asp.net-MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, viewdata

When should I use one versus the other? I want to cache a certain object on startup and reuse around the application.  Which sounds like the better solution (ViewData or Session)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ViewData` is a per-request object used to send information from the controller to the view.
Each action invocation gets its own ViewData; the ViewData doesn't last beyond the view.

[Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) is a per-user storage container which allows you to store data for a specific user session (identified by a cookie)

If you want to share a global object, you should probably make it a singleton (in a `static` property) or put it in Application state.
Make **sure** that it's thread-safe.  (Or use a `[ThreadStatic]` field carefully)